# iPhone X stuck in recovery mode after maxing out storage. Getting "Error Code 14"

Tags: iphone, ios, startup, error, data-recovery

So a couple of weeks ago I restarted my iPhone after it started glitching like crazy, when I tried to boot it up again it got stuck on the Apple logo. A couple of days later I found an article that said something about booting it into recovery mode and then updating it through iTunes would fix it, well big mistake. Now it's stuck in recovery mode. I have tried every possible thing I can think of to boot it out.

Including:

Updating it in iTunes

Updating it in Finder

Switching cables

Switching computers, from Mac to Windows

Using Reiboot to boot it out of recovery mode

Using Reiboot Pro (Paid Version of Reiboot) to "Repair the operating system"

Using 3u tools to repair it.

Using checkra1n to jailbreak it in DFU mode

Using a Windows computer to try to mount the iPhone as a removable storage device

And a couple of other 3rd party tools. None of which have successfully fixed it.
Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

P.S. This iPhone is a business phone with a lot of important information on it that hasn't been backed up in quite a long time, so it's very important for me to try to get the information off of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the iPhone is currently stuck in a reboot loop, try to enter DFU mode and restore it using iTunes.

DFU mode is entered by:

- Connecting to Mac with Lightning cable
- Press Volume Up, then Volume Down quickly
- Press and hold right (Standby) button until display goes dark (about 10 seconds)
- Keep holding Standby and also press Volume Down for 5 seconds
- Keep holding Volume Down, but release Standby button

While the display stays black, iTunes or Finder should say that it found an iPhone in recovery mode and you will be given the choice to return it to factory settings which will wipe the storage and apply the latest firmware.

Entering DFU mode from a reboot loop is very tricky, since it is likely to reboot before you are finished. Try to start the procedure as soon as the Apple logo is displayed and don't be discouraged if you need a few tries.

If that doesn't fix it I would contact Apple, maybe the storage is faulty. Flash storage needs free space for wear leveling and running it near full for a long time can cause a lot faster aging of the memory cells. I would recommend keeping at least 20% free space to counter that.

Comment: I did have a reboot loop on my new iPhone 12 Mini recently after restoring a backup from my iPhone 2020 SE. Entering normal recovery mode was easy, but the recovery option to only update the firmware didn't fix it and I couldn't even enter recovery mode anymore. I then spent at least 20 tries to enter DFU mode and completely wiped the phone, which fixed the boot loop.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!  What you said gives me a good idea of what might be happening with my phone.  I think I will try a couple more things before I try to restore it though.

Comment: What are you basing the "needs free space" bit on?   I have never seen any such recommendation from Apple, so you must have looked in different parts of the documentation than I have.

Comment: Also, wouldn't DFU require restoring the phone, which in turn destroys what is on it right now.  That may not be what is asked for here.

Comment: Yes, it will wipe the storage and reset it to factory settings. You can then restore a backup, so only data that is excluded from backups will be lost. Regarding free space: Those are general recommendations for SSDs to enhance lifetime and performance, it isn't specific to Apple products.